# Access AngularJs directive variable inside controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I'm little bit new to Angularjs. What I want is access "**$scope.myVar**" variable inside '**myController**' controller. It would be great help if you can provide a solution.

```js
angular.module('myDirective', [])
        .controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
               
            }])
        .directive('myDirective', function () {           
            return {
                scope: {
                    myVar: '='                  
                },
                controller: function ($scope) {  
                    $scope.myVar = 'xyz';
                    alert($scope.myVar);
                }
            };
        });
```

```html
<html lang="en-US">  
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="newjavascript.js"></script>
    <body ng-app="myDirective">   
        <div ng-controller="myController">
            <my-directive></my-directive>>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just create a `myVar` variable in your controller and pass it to the directive using `my-var` attribute.

In your `myController`, Define `myVar` as

```
$scope.myVar= "Hello"
```

I your DOM, pass it to the directive as

```
<my-directive my-var="myVar"></my-directive>
```

Since you are using two way binding, any changes made to `myVar` by the directive are available in your controller.

You can put a `watch` on `myVar` to track the changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was scratching my head for ages and this was the missing link (you need bind data between the directive and parent controller via the attribute)

Answer (score 10):

```
angular.module('myDirective', [])
        .controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
               $scope.show = function() {
                   alert($scope.myVar);
               }; 
            }])
        .directive('myDirective', function () {           
            return {
                scope: {
                    myVar: '='                  
                },
                controller: function ($scope) {  
                    $scope.myVar = 'xyz';
                    alert($scope.myVar);
                    $scope.$parent.myVar = $scope.myVar; // here you can access the controller scope by using $parent
                }
             };
        });
```